# Translate Windows NT "cmd /c dir /o:" To AIX

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, aix

The title states my problem but I guess what I really need are some references. Help? Please?

Answer (score 0):

`dir /o` means listing files in sorted order. Use the equivalent `ls` in AIX to achieve the same result. Experiment with option `-t` and `-r` as desired